# Access parent from an array item in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

```
    let vm = {
        title: '',
        value: {},
        items: [{name, text, onClick: ()=> {}],
        selectedItem: ko.observable()
     }
```

This whole vm is bound to an html child component.
When an item in the items array is clicked, I want to notify the parent component
I want to access the selectedItem from the inside the onClick method.
The whole idea is that I want the child to notify the parent when item was clicked

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take:

1. Pass a reference to the `selectedItem` observable to each item when you create the viewmodels in javascript
2. Use knockout's `bindingContext` to resolve a reference to an item's `$parent` viewmodel.

Note: remember that any function bound via the `click` binding will be called with two arguments: (1) the clicked viewmodel, and (2) the click event.

### Approach 1

Here's an example of the first approach:

- Define `selectedItem` before constructing all vms
- Reference it in each item's `onClick`

```js
let selectedItem = ko.observable();

let vm = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "Item 1",
      onClick: self => selectedItem(self)
    },
    {
      name: "Item 2",
      onClick: self => selectedItem(self)
    }
  ],
  
  selectedItem
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p data-bind="with: selectedItem">Selection: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: onClick">Select</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Approach 2

Here's an example of the second approach:

- In the html view, reference `$parent.selectedItem`
- When clicked, knockout will call `selectedItem` as a function passing the clicked data

```js
let vm = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "Item 1",
    },
    {
      name: "Item 2",
    }
  ],
  
  selectedItem: ko.observable()
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p data-bind="with: selectedItem">Selection: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.selectedItem">Select</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```